# Opacity on table cells in Firefox print CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, opacity, printing-web-page

I am trying to apply opacity in a print.css file on table cells.  When printing with Firefox these opaque cells are completely invisible.  The printing is done with "Print Background Colors & Images" unchecked because of other elements on the page.  However on Chrome the printing is done correctly with certain td cells faded but still appearing in place.

**Stylesheet references:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<link type="text/css" href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
```

**The relevant CSS rule from the print.css file:**

```
td.fade {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    -webkit-opacity: 0.3;
    -moz-opacity: 0.3;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

There are some previous rules on all td elements but nothing that should conflict with the opacity.  And this rule is the last rule in the print.css that applies to table cells or parents.

Another strange issue is that print preview in Firefox displays as if it would be printing correctly but it does not.  Is there a bug in Firefox in displaying opacity in the print.css?  I know the print.css is being used because other form elements are not showing when printing due to certain rules in the print.css file.

Comment: BTW the version of Firefox I'm testing with is a current version 19.0

Comment: If you are dealing with solid colours (not images) try using rgba colours instead of opacity

Comment: Printing is in my experience not the most cared about topic at Firefox development.
There was once this bug filed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=262019 with this example: http://fvsch.com/code/bugs/ff4-print-opacity/

Which OS you are on?

Comment: Btw, leading 0 at a property value is never necessary.

Comment: Tested on Windows 7 and Windows XP

Comment: Why would you want opacity for print, if you are not even printing any background colors/images? If this is just for the layout to look good on screen, you could just overwrite the opactiy in a print stylesheet. (Or the other way around, declare opacity for media=print only.)

Answer (score 1):

Rafe mentioned this in a comment, but I don't know why he did not offer it as an answer. Using `rgba()` colors works to get faded text in Firefox to print. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhJzU/2/) with this code:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Test No Fade</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test Fade 70%</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test Fade 50%</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test Fade 30%</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr + tr td {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
tr + tr + tr td {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
tr + tr + tr + tr td {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Since you are not printing background colors and images, then I suggest all your `.fade` classes switch to `rgba()` for the `color` of the text for print media.

Answer (score 1):

**moz-opacity** is one way and there is another way of **rgba color code** having alpha value which gives transparancy to the colors..

Answer (score 0):

The Crome printing is done using a separate driver they have inbuilt, which takes image like snap from the page and transfers to printer, to verify, install PDF printer and print a page, the page will be in form of image, the text is not select-able.

Now while printing the opacity. Its just a media="screen" effect. In media="print" this will not be applied with printer, as the file spooling will be done character bye character(or line by line, but will be applied in printer.)

Solution: for print.css or media="print" I have one one thing to say,

reduce color contrast. if border-color:#000; for opacity 0.3 it may lead to nearby color is:#888.

This will do, the opacity is filter, which applies to screen will not work on printer.

I hope things are clear after reading this :)

thank you,